# Localizing google maps panning hint

Tags: javascript, google-maps, localization

When Google Map's `div` is being opened in a web page and the page is being shown up in a mobile/touch device, if user tries to move his/her finger on the surface area of the map `div`, the map div is being highlighted, showing up the sentence

> Use two fingers to move the map

Is there any way to localize the string via Google Map's JavaScript API?

Comment: *"By default, the Google Maps JavaScript API uses the user's preferred language setting as specified in the browser, when displaying textual information"* [Localization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('p.gm-style-pbt').css('font-family', 'your desired font');
                $('p.gm-style-pbt').css('font-size', 'your desired size');
                $("p.gm-style-pbt").html('localized string');
            });
```